# Make edits to a webpage and save the changes locally

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, contenteditable

I am wanting to find a way I can have others edit a html webpage (found locally) and allow them to save the changes they have made.

I know this is an odd request, I have a very specific idea in mind, which I will include below as an optional read for those interested.

I found that this code in the address bar works for the editing: `document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0`

Then I found that just adding:

```
 <div id="columns" contentEditable="true">
```

gets the job done since I can edit the html.

The problem is that I cannot save the changes. I have tried saving the page in several different formats, including webpage/complete, HTML only, TXT file.

Is there anyway to save these edits whether by saving the HTML or using some other kind of simple storage?

Reasoning:
I have a simple local html page I will be using with other co-workers. These co-workers are not very tech-savvy (even less than me). The very mention of trying to explain how to edit the html and make changes to the text created blank stares, and an unwillingness to work on the project. I would very much prefer for them to be able to edit the text of this HTML page from the front end and not mess up any of the coding. 
Also, I have installed a Xampp server, and wordpress - this has become a bit overkill for the purpose and again, has confused the others.

Thanks,

Comment: If you also want other users to see the updated pages, you need server script to update your page on the servers.  Without server side scripting, the changes won't be seen by other users or persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/) to save the data in the user's browser.

Comment: Okay, I checked that out. Sorry seems like a completely different language to me. Where would I put this code, or how would I use it in relation to a local HTML? I apologize for my lack of knowledge, I have been searching for a simple explanation on how to use it.

Comment: localStorage is an API available on newer browsers that you can manipulate with JavaScript. I think is the only easy way to accomplish what you want. Here is a small tutorial: http://www.arungudelli.com/html5/html5-local-storage-tutorial/ Basically, you set a key, value pair, where your value would be the content of your editable div.

Comment: I'm so darn stupid. I figured out how to use it in this page's source code. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Go into JavaScript. Select and right-click on . Click copy as html. Then save into a .txt file somewhere. If you want to restore the website, right-click on  and select Edit as html. Copy/paste the code in. Then it's back to normal.